# Julia: writing matrix with NaN values to binary file

Tags: julia

I have a matrix containing Float64's and possibly some NaN entries. I would like to save it to file as a file in binary (as this is fastest and speed is important here) e.g.,

```
io = open(string(saveto_dir,"/arr"),"w")
@time write(io,arr) 
close(io)
```

However Julia gives the error message:

```
`write` is not supported on non-isbits arrays
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: can you show the `arr` (or slice of it)? The error you show does not match the description. `NaN` is a normal `Float64` value. However, in general you can consider using serialization and write your data using `serialize` and read using `deserialize` (this is the simplest option in my experience that does not require installing any packages as `Serialization` module is bundled with Julia installation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this is due to (perhaps inadvertently) using an `Array` of type `Any` (i.e., `Array{Any}`), but if your data is as described you can use an `Array{Float64}` instead, in which case you will not have this problem.

To give a concrete example, writing

```
arr = Any[1.0, NaN]
io = open("./arr","w")
write(io,arr) 
close(io)
```

gives exactly the error you describe, but if you just change that to

```
arr = Float64[1.0, NaN]
io = open("./arr","w")
write(io,arr) 
close(io)
```

there is no error.

In general, one should vehemently avoid `Array{Any}` (or really anything involving `Any`) when there is any other practicable option, effectively due to [type instability](https://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2013/12/06/writing-type-stable-code-in-julia/). For example:

```
julia> A = rand(10000); # Array{Float64}

julia> B = Any[A...]; # Array{Any}

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @benchmark sum($A)
BechmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 10 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  1.318 μs …  12.705 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     1.347 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   1.400 μs ± 269.376 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  ▇█▅▂▂▂      ▃       ▂▂                                    ▁ ▂
  ██████▇▆▁▅▅███▇▁▃▃▁▁██▆▅▃▄▃▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▃▃▁▃▁▁▃▁▁▁▃▁▁▃▁▇█ █
  1.32 μs      Histogram: log(frequency) by time      2.62 μs <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.

julia> @benchmark sum($B)
BechmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  185.967 μs …  1.664 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 75.01%
 Time  (median):     195.609 μs              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   213.615 μs ± 62.394 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  1.31% ±  4.62%

  ▅██▅▄▅▃▃▂▂▄▃▁▂▁▁▂▄▁▁    ▃▃                                 ▂ ▂
  ███████████████████████▇████▆▆▇▆▄▄▄▃▄▃▅▄▄▅▄▁▅▃▄▅▅▃▄▃▃▄▄▅▁▄▅█ █
  186 μs        Histogram: log(frequency) by time       413 μs <

 Memory estimate: 156.23 KiB, allocs estimate: 9999.
```

About a 100x performance difference is fairly typical (notice also the difference in number of allocations).

Comment: thanks! can you advise me why using  Array{Any} is bad for other reasons? In particular could there be performance problems if I use this declaration for large arrays?

Comment: Yes, definitely the `Any` version will be much slower. This is due to what's called _type instability_, which is when Julia can't figure out what types things are supposed to be, and results in huge numbers of allocations and massively slower code. Sometimes this may happen inadvertently, but if you specify the type as `Any` that's basically telling the compiler to just give up, and will automatically be unstable.

Comment: Type instability is a common gotcha when moving to Julia, because it's pretty much a unique concept to dispatch-oriented languages.